# EmberJs Getting an img src to bind multiple model attributes correctly

Tags: templates, ember.js, laravel-4, handlebars.js

I am trying to learn EmberJs, in conjuction with Laravel 4, to create a blog. Things have been going great, stuff hasn't been too difficult yet. But I got into a snag when trying to have a `<img/>` tag in one of my handlebar templates.

From my understanding to use info from a model in a template you use `{{attribute_name}}` and like magic, it's there! And so for my tag I was trying something like:

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('images/posts/')}}@{{id}}.@{{image_extension}}" }}" alt=""/>
```

Adding the url to images with Laravel and Blade, then on the template, just adding in those last little pieces to make the it all work. But I get this instead:

```
<img src="http://localhost/blog/images/posts&lt;script id='metamorph-11-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;26&lt;script id='metamorph-11-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;.&lt;script id='metamorph-12-start' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;jpg&lt;script id='metamorph-12-end' type='text/x-placeholder'&gt;&lt;/script&gt;" alt="">
```

Obviously theres script tags in my src tag and this is causing some issues.

Now then, upon much research I discovered `{{unbound attribute_name}}` and came up with:

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('images/posts')}}/@{{unbound id}}.@{{unbound image_extension}}" alt=""/>
```

and while this works on the first blog post I click, it doesn't switch images when I switch posts.

```
<img src="{{URL::asset('images/posts')}}/@{{bind-attr src=id}}.@{{bind-attr src=image_extension}}" alt="Post image"/>
```

and it feels like it's on the right path, but not quite there. Any more advice?

So is there a way to make this guy work? I'm running out of ideas! Any information you could shed on this would be great! I really like ember so far and want to get even better! IF there's any more info you need, let em know and I will edit this question! Thanks so much!

Comment: what's this, `URL::asset('images/posts')` I'm unfamiliar with double colon outside the context of class bindings?

Comment: This is from Laravel this is a helper class for putting out the base URL. IT also uses The {{}} but is not handlebar stuff.

Comment: So that'd be injected before the template is processed?

Comment: Yes, it would look like `http://localhost/blog/images/posts`

Answer (score 1):

In your case I'd recommend making the Laravel portion part of a global property.

Then you'd be better off adding a computed property to the controller and use `bind-attr`

```
<img {{bind-attr src=imageProperty}} />
```

Then in the scoped controller

```
imageProperty: function(){
   return App.postsImages + this.get('color') + ".jpg";
}.property('color')
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/foper/2/edit